# Angularjs When to use track-by over select-as in ng-options directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-track-by

I would like to know in which situations is recommended to use *track by* over *select as* in ng-options directive?

Here we have the two options:

```
<select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" ng-model="selectedItemSA">

<select ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selectedItemTB">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-init="items = [{id: 1, name: 'item1'}, {id: 2, name: 'item2'}]">
  
    <div>
      <h2>Using select as</h2>
      <select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" ng-model="selectedItemSA">
      </select>
      <button ng-click="selectedItemSA = 2;">Select item 2</button>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <h2>Using track by</h2>      
      <select ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selectedItemTB">
      </select>
      <button ng-click="selectedItemTB = {id: 2, name: 'item2'};">Select item 2</button>
    </div>  
        
  </div>
</div>
```

We can see the html result is the same:

```
  <div>
    <h2>Using select as</h2>
    <select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" ng-model="selectedItemSA" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
      <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
      <option label="item1" value="number:1">item1</option>
      <option label="item2" value="number:2">item2</option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="selectedItemSA = 2;">Select item 2</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Using track by</h2>
    <select ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selectedItemTB" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
      <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
      <option label="item1" value="1">item1</option>
      <option label="item2" value="2">item2</option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="selectedItemTB = {id: 2, name: 'item2'};">Select item 2</button>
  </div>
```

To select an item with *select as* we must do:

```
selectedItemSA = 2;
```

To select an item with *track by* we must do:

```
selectedItemTB = {id: 2, name: 'item2'};
```

Most of the times I will have access just to the item id, or just it will be more easy to use the item id than the whole object. So I will always prefer to use *select as* over *track by*.

Do you know a situation where *track by* would be the preferable option?